# Trace of $u$ on bottom edge of a square if $u_x=0$ inside the square

Tags: sobolev-spaces, traces

I want to show that:

Let $\Omega =(0,1)\times (0,1)$. For $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, if $u_x=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$, then the trace of $u$ on bottom edge $y=0$, i.e., $u\left|_{y=0}\right.$, is a constant.

The result seems be too obvious, but a simple thing is often difficult to prove/explain.

Below is my argument. I would like to know is this a standard proof, or is there wrong usage of basic theorems of Sobolev spaces.

> Proof:  Since $u_x=0$ a.e. in $\Omega$ and $\Omega$ is simply-connected, $u$ is essentially a function $v(y)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$, which has only one variable $y$. As $v(y)$ can be regarded as a function in $H^1(0,1)$, the embedding theorem on 1D implies  $v(y) \in C([0,1])$. Thus we can take the value of $v(0)$, which just the trace of $u$ on bottom edge.

If the proof is given from the level of "density of $C^1(\Omega)\cap H^1(\Omega)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$", what shall I do?